MGT components in custom (Angular) MS Teams App no longer working
I have a custom Microsoft Teams application built with Angular. Until recently, all various authentication pipelines were working using SSO "onBehalf". The main authentication areas are:

Custom (dotnet core) WebAPI

Microsoft Graph API

Microsoft Grapy Toolkit (MGT) components, like mgt-login, etc. 


After updating to
@azure/msal-angular (3.0.17)
@azure/msal-browser (3.14.0)
@microsoft/mgt (4.2.1)
@microsoft/mgt-element (4.2.1)
@microsoft/mgt-teamsfx-provider (4.2.1)
The Microsoft Graph Toolkit components are no longer working. (custom api and graph api still are working fine).
The error message I get is:
Cannot get access token due to error: ErrorWithCode.UiRequiredError: Failed to get access token cache silently, please login first: you need login first before get access token.
I've trying to fix the error for quite some time now. Anybody have an idea what is going on? How to fix this?
Thank you,
--tolga
Banged my head against the wall. My head is now flat

It appears that there's an issue with the token acquisition process after updating the MSAL libraries. Please ensure that the MSAL and MGT configurations are correct and review the authentication flow. Additionally, consider enabling logging to gather more details on the error.

Instead of using same published App Registration, please try using a new one and let us know if they face same issue
